# Disc brakes sometimes sing

Tags: disc-brake

[image]Sometimes my front disc brakes on my mountain bike "sing" when I am NOT applying them.

The pictures show there is a space between the pad and the rotor.

It can get irritating.

Is there some kind of fix?

[image]

Comment: Give them tickets to the opera—sounds like they’re musically deprived ;)

Comment: @MaplePanda Don't try to get a job as a comedian. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have checked if the brake disks are mounted securely. You may want to check alignment of the caliper, and you may want to check if both brake pads retract correctly after releasing the brakes.
If both are file, it's possible, according to my experience, that sometimes a bit of grit, sand or such gets picked up by the brakes. Typically, that would go away immediately when applying the brakes.

If none of this is the case, i think we need more information.

Comment: The brakes are mounted securely.

Answer (score 2):

After disassembling the disc brake assembly and cleaning it thoroughly,
the noise went away.

There was some lint and "grease" looking substance that was removed.